# improve html to improve performance of itextsharp

Tags: html, vb.net, itext

i´m converting HTML to PDF with itextsharp, i have improved the the code in itextsharp side, following this thread [iTextSharp XMLWorker parsing really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275800/itextsharp-xmlworker-parsing-really-slow) 
but now i need to improve in html too. My goal is reach a time lowest than 0,1 seconds, i'm getting now 0,4 seconds

I don't know what are the rules in html side for a fatest rendering in itextsharp. In my HTML template basically i have style inline html and all is done with tables, here i let you the code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DOCUMENT</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- 2 -->
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <tr>
        <!-- DETALLE DE LECTURA/CONSUMO OK-->
        <td width="60%" style="padding-right:5px" valign="top">
          <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" style="border:1px solid #2F3640;background-color:#2F3640;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;padding: 2px 5px;font-size:10pt;">DETALLE DE LECTURA/CONSUMO</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td>Consumo &Uacute;ltimos 13 Meses (KWHs)</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                          <!-- GRAFICO DE CONSUMO -->
                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                            <!--BARRAS-->
                            <tr>
                              <td width="100%">
                                <table width="100%" style="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                    <tr style="font-size:5pt;height:130px;">
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:4%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 1 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-1]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-1-px]px; background-color:black">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 2 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-2]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-2-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 3 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-3]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-3-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 4 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-4]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-4-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 5 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-5]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-5-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 6 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-6]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-6-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 7 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-7]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-7-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 8 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-8]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-8-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 9 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-9]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-9-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 10 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-10]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-10-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 11 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-11]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-11-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 12 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-12]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-12-px]px; background-color:gray">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
                                      <!-- MES 13 -->
                                      <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
                                        <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">[valor-grafico-13]</p>
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:[valor-grafico-13-px]px; background-color:black">
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <!-- -->
                                      <td style="font-size:5pt;width:4%"></td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- EJE -->
                            <tr style="background-color:black; padding: 0; height: 1px">
                              <td colspan="26" nowrap="" >
                                <div></div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- MESES -->
                            <tr>
                              <td width="100%">
                                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="4%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-1]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-2]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-3]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-4]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-5]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-6]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-7]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-8]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-9]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-10]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-11]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-12]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">[mes-13]</td>
                                    <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="4%"></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>       
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;">
                    <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Datos consumo desde: [fecha-inicio-consumo]</td>
                        <td width="50%">hasta: [fecha-hasta-consumo]</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" >
                          <table width="100%" style="font-size:10pt;text-align:center;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                            <tr>
                              <th>Medidores</th>
                              <th>Lectura Actual</th>
                              <th>Lectura Anterior</th>
                              <th>Diferencia</th>
                              <th>Constante</th>
                              <th>KWH</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>[medidor-1]</td>
                              <td>[lectura-actual-1]</td>
                              <td>[lectura-anterior-1]</td>
                              <td>[diferencia-1]</td>
                              <td>[constante-1]</td>
                              <td>[kwh-1]</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                              <td>[XX]</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:5px" colspan="2">
                          <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;text-align:right" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="80%" style="font-size:10pt;">Consumo Energia(KWH/mensual)</td>
                              <td width="20%" style="font-size:10pt;">[consumo-energia]</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="80%" style="font-size:10pt;">Consumo Energia Invierno(KWH/mensual)</td>
                              <td width="20%" ="font-size:10pt;">[consumo-energia-invierno]</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="80%">Potencia Contratada o Le&iacute;da (KW)</td>
                              <td>[potencia-contratada]</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="80%">Potencia Contratada o Le&iacute;da Horas de Punta(KW)</td>
                              <td>[potencia-hora-punta]</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>              
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
        </td>
        <td width="40%">
          <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img width="180px" src="http://localhost/FE.images/SEC.jpg" alt="sec"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- ACUSE DE RECIBO -->
                <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="40%">Recinto:</td>
                    <td width="60%" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td>
                    <td width="60%" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Fecha:</td>
                    <td width="60%" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>RUT:</td>
                    <td width="60%" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">FIRMA</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- 3 -->
    <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <tr>
        <td width="65%">
          <table width="100%" style="padding-right:5px; font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
            <tr>
              <td style="border:1px solid #2F3640;background-color:#2F3640;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;padding: 2px 5px;font-size:10pt;">
                DETALLE DE LA CUENTA FACTURACION
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%"  style="font-size:8pt;line-height:9pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="70%" style="font-size:10pt;" >Cargo fijo mensual</td>
                    <td width="30%" style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[cargo-fijo-mensual]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">Cargo &uacute;nico del sistema troncal ([cantidad-energia] kWh)</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[cargo-unico]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">Cargo por energ&iacute;a base ([cantidad-energia] kWh)</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[cargo-energia-base]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">Cargo por energ&iacute;a adicional de invierno ([cantidad-energia] kWh)</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[cargo-energia-invierno]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;font-size:10pt;" width="70%">Reliquidaciones</td>
                    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;text-align:right;font-size:10pt;" width="30%">$[reliquidaciones]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">Calibracion de medidor</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[calibracion-medidor]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">Inter&eacute;s por mora</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[interes-mora]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">Compensaciones</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[compensaciones]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-1]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-2]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-3]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-4]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-5]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-6]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-7]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-8]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-9]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10pt;">item</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[item-10]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="70%" style="border-top:1px solid black;padding-top:5px;font-size:10pt;">Total:</td>
                    <td width="30%" style="border-top:1px solid black;padding-top:5px;text-align:right;font-size:10pt;">$[total-pagar]</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <!-- TOTALES -->
        <td width="35%">
          <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" align="left">
                <table width="95%" style="font-size:8pt;border:2px solid black;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                  <tr>
                    <th style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">DETALLE DE ABONOS</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Total Abonados:</td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Fecha Abono:</td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Comprobante Caja &#8470;:</td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="100%">
                <table width="100%" style="font-size:8pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                  <tr>


                    <td width="50%" style="font-size:10pt;">Fecha vencimiento:</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="font-size:10pt;">[fecha-vencimiento]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%" style="font-size:10pt;">Fecha de corte de suministro:</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="font-size:10pt;">[fecha-corte]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%" style="font-size:10pt;">&Uacute;ltimo pago realizado:</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="font-size:10pt;">[fecha-ultimo-pago]</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <table width="100%" style="background-color:black;color:white;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" >TOTAL:</td>
                        <td width="50%" style="background-color:black;color:white;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;";>[total-pagar]</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <img width="280px" src="#" alt="timbre"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this has been addressed in the most recent version but as of 5.5.5 there was an issue in regards to the `ImageProvider`. If you don't explicitly set an `ImageProvider` iTextSharp will internally throw an exception, catch it and create an `ImageProvider` on your behalf. Unfortunately this can happen dozens or hundreds of times depending on how much HTML your are processing.

The quick fix is to just explicitly set your own `ImageProvider`. This can be just a simple so called "blank image provider" as [shown here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1897454.aspx#5680466) or you could make a more complex one.

Here's a VB.Net version:

```
Public Class BlankImageProvider
    Implements IImageProvider

    Public Function GetImageRootPath() As String Implements IImageProvider.GetImageRootPath
        Return ""
    End Function

    Public Sub Reset() Implements IImageProvider.Reset

    End Sub

    Public Function Retrieve(src As String) As iTextSharp.text.Image Implements IImageProvider.Retrieve
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub Store(src As String, img As iTextSharp.text.Image) Implements IImageProvider.Store

    End Sub
End Class
```

To use it you just need to bind it to your `HtmlPipelineContext` object using the `SetImageProvider` method:

```
htmlContext.SetImageProvider(New BlankImageProvider())
```

Also, I don't know if this factors in but your HTML is technically not accurate in several places. For instance, you are using `px` in your HTML attributes but in reality you can only use numbers or numbers with a percent sign. For instance, `cellpadding="0px"` is invalid and should be `cellpadding="0"`. You also have at least one `<table>` tag that is directly a child of a `<tr>` but instead there should be an intermediary `<td>` or `<th>` tag. These things may or may not affect iTextSharp's speed but it might make things more future-proof to fix.