# MVCRazorToPdf (iTextSharp) using custom font

Tags: c#, itext, mvcrazortopdf

I am trying to add a custom font to my pdf output using the nuget package MVCRazorToPdf but I am having trouble with how to do this as the documentation for iTextSharp isn't great and all seems to be outdated.

The current code I have for creating the pdf is:

```
return new PdfActionResult(
    "test.cshtml", 
    new TestModel(),
    (writer, document) =>
    {
        FontFactory.Register(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/content/fonts/vegur-regular-webfont.ttf"), "VegurRegular");
    });
```

Where `writer` is a `PdfWriter` and `document` is a `Document`

All the examples of using the `FontFactory` show that you need to use the `XmlWorker` but I don't have access to that, so I was wondering if there was any way to change the documents font using the `writer` or `document`?

I've seen that there is the `document.HtmlStyleClass` property but can't find anything about how to use this anywhere.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Most of the itextpdf examples are for the Java version, but a developer shouldn't have any problems porting Java to C#. The itext specific things are identical between Java and C#.

Comment: Xmlworker is also available as a NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/

Comment: I have that installed - it gets downloaded as part of the MvcRazorToPdf package

Comment: I am confused, in your question you wrote that you do not have access to xmlworker?

Comment: The mvctrazortopdf package converts the razor view to a pdf using the above function, it only exposes the writer and the document and does all the worker stuff behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`MVCRazorToPdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcRazorToPdf/) is a very, very simple wrapper around iTextSharp's `XMLWorker` and uses the even simpler `XMLWorkerHelper` with all defaults to do its work. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/blob/master/MvcRazorToPdf/MvcRazorToPdf.cs) you'll see this:

```
                document.Open();


                using (var reader = new StringReader(RenderRazorView(context, viewName)))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, reader);

                    document.Close();
                    output = workStream.ToArray();
                }
```

If you're dead-set on using the NuGet version then you're stuck with this implementation and you're not going to be able to register a custom font.

However, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/issues/21) regarding this that [includes a fix](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/issues/21#issuecomment-129858670) so if you're willing to [compile from source](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/) you can apply that change and you should be all set.

If you want to go one step further I'd recommend reading [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25164257/231316) that shows how simple parsing HTML with iTextSharp is as well [Bruno's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220259/231316) that shows how to register fonts.

**EDIT**

As per the post in the includes a fix link (just in case the link breaks in future), change the above `using` statement to:

```
        using (var reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RenderRazorView(context, viewName))))
        {
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, reader, null, FontFactory.FontImp as IFontProvider);

            document.Close();
            output = workStream.ToArray();
        }
```

And then the font factory as registered in the question above will work when using `style="font-family:VegurRegular;"`

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I needed - I had to edit the source anyway as I needed to merge it with an existing pdf, I just couldn't figure out how to change that xmlworkerhelper to use the new fontfactory