# I'm having problems with CSS in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, itext

I am having problems with making a PDF file from HTML code with CSS.

The PDF is being made, but without any of the CSS provided in the code.

I've searched all over the place and found plenty of example codes and such, but none of them have worked for me.

--

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/IText-XMLWorker-amp-CSS-td4471515.html

I could not get the example on this page to work. The **handler.getCSS()** was not available.

--

http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html

This page tells me I need to use **iTextSharp.tool.xml.css**, or iTextPDF

Is there perhaps a difference between **iTextSharp** and **iTextPDF**?

--

What is the simplest way to get CSS into the following code:

I can make the CSS a seperate file, if that will make it easier.

```
public static void ConvertToPDFNow(string FileName, string HTML){
    Document document = new Document();

    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Domains\example.com\Arkiv\" + FileName, FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();

    iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper helper = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
    helper.ParseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(@HTML));

    document.Close();


    Utilities.ShowPdf(@"C:\Domains\example.com\Arkiv\" + FileName);
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16105368/231316

Comment: For some reason, **IElementHandler** is not available. I cannot find any documentation that tells how to use get it... perhaps I am using an older version of something?

Comment: `IElementHandler` is in the `itextsharp.xmlworker.dll` library in the `iTextSharp.tool.xml` namespace. You need two DLLs for this, do you have both referenced? http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/

Comment: Silly me... I thought I had that, but I had only a bunch of sub-namespaces... that explains alot of problems I've been having :P