# iTextSharp convering database HTML content to an open document

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I have a process that converts "text" content to PDF. All "text" is stored in a database.
We have recently added HTML content to the UI and database.  So, I need to modify the pdf generation process to, "on the fly," convert HTML to PDF.   I would like to use the XMLParser, but all of the examples show opening a new document - the process I need is to convert HTML to a PDF paragraph to push into an open document.   Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "open document"? Do you mean you have an existing PDF document that you're modifying using something like a `PdfStamper` or do you mean a new document that you've added some text to and at a certain part of your process you need to parse and add some HTML? If the latter see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15362705/231316

Comment: Sounds more like a job for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf to me.