# Generating PDF with Print button on .NET

Tags: itext, pechkin, tuespechkin

I have a requirement to dynamically generate a PDF document from HTML that includes a button that will trigger the PDF print dialog, when viewed in either a browser or Adobe Acrobar Reader, or any program that displays PDFs.

I currently use iTextSharp.XmlWriter, not sure if it is possible to achieve with that, or any other lib, like Pechkin?

Comment: I think you're going to need to us [`ParseToList`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15362705/231316) and manually inspect each element looking for your print button. When you find it you're then going to need to manually create a button and add it at the current location. To the best of my knowledge, iText doesn't have any native handler for a special-case "print" button.